# VPN Error: any valid prefix is expected rather than "local/32"

Tags: vpn, openconnect

I usually connect to the same VPN and today I got this error:

`Error: any valid prefix is expected rather than "local/32"`

Any idea to fix it?

I am using Ubuntu 21.10, 64 bit
GNOME Version 40.4.0

Comment: https://gitlab.com/openconnect/vpnc-scripts/-/issues/10

Comment: No this does not solve the issue. The author of the post wrote "That issue has been resolved, I am closing it" without sharing the solution.

Comment: What VPN are you using?

Comment: Thanks @David. I am using openconnect.

Comment: OpenConnect does have its own support forum. https://forum.devolutions.net/topics/29033/support-for-openconnect